# Is it possible to use a BHO (IE8) to track which links a user clicks

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, bho

Reading about BHOs and I know I can see ways in which you can track a user's navigation - however - is it possible with a BHO to identify which link was clicked by a user (for instance - if two links exist on a page in which a user can click to navigate to destination a - is it possible to determine which link was actually clicked)?

Answer (score 1):

You can [sink the DISPID_HTMLELEMENTEVENTS2_ONCLICK event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you can get access to the elements (sometimes you don't such as elements in a frame in another domain)

Oh, and remember to detach your events in BeforeNavigate2.

An issue is there is no reliable way to detect a page refresh to reconnect the events or handle elements generated from scripts (Ajax).

Comment: Note that this won't work well with AJAX pages that modify the DOM after the DocumentComplete event, and add links to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. A BHO is C++ code running inside the IE process, so it has access to all the memory and can do pretty much anything within it (doing stuff to things outside of the process is a separate topic, and is severely limited by IE).

Comment: No, I will not show sample code or tell you how to do it. I've worked for the last three years on BHOs at Microsoft, and we partnered closely with the IE team. So, I've heard enough horror stories, and have first hands witnessed (and caused internally :-)) the havoc on the user experience a badly written or malicious BHO can wreak.

Comment: You gave me some ideas - would i be along the right path doing something similar to this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/jsinjectbhoplugincsharp.aspx

Comment: Oh my god! Do not inject HTML or JS in the page! There is no safe way to guarantee you will not break the page itself by doing so. It's ideas like this that lead users to believe IE is the monster everyone depicts it to be. :-(((

Comment: Alos, do NOT use C# to write BHOs! Couple of reasons - 1) you don't own the process, so you can't guarantee the right .Net version is loaded, so you might conflict with another BHO; 2) this will have severe impact on the memory set and the performance of the browser.

Comment: CLR in Explorer/IE problem has diminished in .NET 4.0 onwards with decent SxS story, but that doesn't make loading CLR objects into Explorer/IE any less evil.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got two identical links and you want to know which was clicked?

Why not just add a unique URL parameter to each one:

```
<a href='mylink.html?tracking=linkA'>click me</a>
<a href='mylink.html?tracking=linkB'>click me</a>
```

Then your server logs will tell you which one was clicked. No need for any IE-specific hacks.

Comment: I wouldn't have any control over the sites in which a user may navigate - so this wouldn't work.