# How to invoke an already running instance of an application

Tags: javascript, c++, internet-explorer, bho

I am developing a BHO with c++ for identifying the phone numbers on any webpage, highlighting the phone numbers and invoking an utility when click on the phone number.

I am using IHtmlTxtRange::findtext for finding the phone numbers and for  highlighting the phone numbers I am injecting HTML's span tag to the web page using IHtmlTxtRange::pastetext().

I want to invoke the same instance of an already running application, when click on the phone number on web page . How to achieve this with onclick() of HTML span tag.

Below I have given the code snippet which I am using for finding and highlighting the phone number.

```
lpBody->createTextRange(&lpTxtRange);

lpBody->Release();

CComBSTR html;

CComBSTR newhtml;

long t;

VARIANT_BOOL bFound;

int i=0;

int size= findText.size();

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)

{   

    while(1)

    {

        CComBSTR str1= findText[i].c_str();

        lpTxtRange->findText(str1,0,lFlags,&bFound);

        if(bFound==-1)

        {

            newhtml.Empty();

            lpTxtRange->get_htmlText(&html);

            newhtml.Append("<span id='");

            newhtml.Append(L"begin_highlight");

            newhtml.Append("' title='");

            newhtml.Append(L"call this phone number ");

            newhtml.Append(str1);

            newhtml.Append("' style='");

            newhtml.Append(L"color: white; background-color: grey");

            newhtml.Append("'>");

            newhtml.AppendBSTR(html);

            newhtml.Append("</span>");

            lpTxtRange->pasteHTML(newhtml);

            lpTxtRange->moveStart((BSTR)CComBSTR("Character"),1,&t);

            lpTxtRange->moveEnd((BSTR)CComBSTR("Textedit"),1,&t);

        }

        else

             break;

    }



}



lpTxtRange->Release();

findText.clear();
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This may help with half of your problem..

You can use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the window of your running application.  To identify the window as being your application, you can use the class name of the window (which you could use a GUID for).  `GetClassNameA` should get this from your HWND.

In the app that you are sending the data to, be sure to set this class name up when the main window is created.

To actually send the data to it, you can send it a [WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command using `SendMessage` and a [COPYDATASTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The receiving application then need to receive this via its message loop.

All that is left then is getting a callback in the BHO when you item is clicked to do all of this!

Edit: this could be of use for that:
[Is it possible to use a BHO (IE8) to track which links a user clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829340/is-it-possible-to-use-a-bho-ie8-to-track-which-links-a-user-clicks)